# -/+ buffers/cache & Swap

Tags: memory, swap, cache

When should the usage of swap get started? or

How do I know that my swap is being used? At least some times if not always, considering the default swappiness of `60`

Also, *why* does `free` offer to omit the buffers/cache line, shouldn't it be considered? I've always referred just `free -got`'s output.

My memory stats is as below, have never seen the swap being used, at all.
Has the buffers/cache something to do in regards?

```
-bash-3.2$ free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64458      24419      40039          0         38        212
-/+ buffers/cache:      24167      40290
Swap:        16386          0      16386
Total:       80845      24419      56425
```

The swappiness value is the default one.

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

Need to know these as I've had the situations wherein **all** of my 62Gigs RAM was used.

Please enlighten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I know that my swap is being used?
>
> have never seen the swap being used, at all.

Try to create memory pressure in order to make Linux page-out pages. On my system swap was also 0. Then I run `stress --vm 30`. Here is a help on strees:

```
$ stress --help
`stress' imposes certain types of compute stress on your system

Usage: stress [OPTION [ARG]] ...
 ....
 -m, --vm N         spawn N workers spinning on malloc()/free()
     --vm-bytes B   malloc B bytes per vm worker (default is 256MB)
     --vm-stride B  touch a byte every B bytes (default is 4096)
     --vm-hang N    sleep N secs before free (default none, 0 is inf)
     --vm-keep      redirty memory instead of freeing and reallocating
```

30 instances of `strees` cause memory pressure and Linux started page-out pages, which was clear from `vmstat 1`. See for `so` column:

```
man vmstat:
   Swap
       si: Amount of memory swapped in from disk (/s).
       so: Amount of memory swapped to disk (/s).
```

vmstat report:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
98  0  0    
 0  0      0 3355728 112016 2052000    0    0     0     0  287  335  3  1 96  0  0  
30  0      0 358472 112016 2052000    0    0     0     0 1575 1012  7 74 19  0  0   
14 33 141588  99032  60252 1578948  268 141764   404 142080 6896 3249  3 93  0  4  0    
31 24 302632  98664  17208 1020240 8280 165008  8308 165236 5686 4114  5 76  0 20  0    
11 22 494516  98732   4208 615496 3112 191952 11552 192060 5494 5199  2 64  1 33  0
```

And swap used became big enough:

```
             total   used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7228   1411       5816          0         23        171
-/+ buffers/cache:   1217       6011
Swap:         4647        824       3823
Total:       11876   2236       9640
```